# Localizing CharFields and ModelForms with choices in Django

Tags: django, localization, django-forms

I have a Model and ModelForm like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Item(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        choices=(
            ('car', _("Cars")),
            ('computers', _("Computers")),
            ('furry animal', _("Furry or large animals")),
            ))


class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
```

I have properly catalogued, translated and compiled the strings, and `{% trans "Cars" %}` shows the translated text as expected.

Now if I pass instances of `ItemForm` and `Item` to a template, and use them as `{{ form }}` and `{{ item.category }}`, am I correct to assume that they will not by default show the localized choices?

What would be the cleanest and simplest way of having them localized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this yourself?

I'm pretty sure they *would* be localized. At least `{{ form }}`, whereas you would want to use `{{ item.get_category_display }}` to get the display value for the `category` field (i.e. "Furry or large animals"/"Pelzige oder grosse Tiere" (localized) rather than "furry animal" (internal string)).

Comment: You're right on both accounts. The `get_xyz_display` was new to me, thanks! The form I described is actually working just fine, and my real problem was with `ModelChoiceField` (generated from ForeignKey), which wouldn't translate even though I had the foreign model's contents translated. The solution was to make the foreign model's `__unicode__`-method do a `ugettext` for the result. Don't know if it's the proper way to do it, but all my testcases pass so I'm happy. Anyway thanks for pointing me to the right direction. :-)